# jQuery SP.JS objects to test if current SharePoint user has full control / owner rigths?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, jquery, security, spservices

As an example, the below jQuery displays current SharePoint user title. Excellent! :)

Is it possible to use the sp.js objects  to test  If the current user has Full Control on the current page or Site and send an alert if they do?

Many Thanks.

```
var context;
var web;
var user;

// This code runs when the DOM is ready. It ensures the SharePoint
// script file sp.js is loaded and then executes sharePointReady()
$(document).ready(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);
});

// This function creates a context object which is needed to use the SharePoint object model
function sharePointReady() {
    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = context.get_web();

    getUserName();
}

// This function prepares, loads, and then executes a SharePoint query to get the current users information
function getUserName() {
    user = web.get_currentUser();
    context.load(user);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onGetUserNameSuccess, onGetUserNameFail);
}

// This function is executed if the above call is successful
// It replaces the contents of the 'helloString' element with the user name
function onGetUserNameSuccess() {
    $('#message').text('Hello ' + user.get_title());
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use Sharepoint Client Object Model for this. Here is how to do it on the current web:

```
function CheckPermissionOnWeb() 
{
    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    web = context.get_web();

    this._currentUser = web.get_currentUser();

    context.load(this._currentUser);

    context.load(web,'EffectiveBasePermissions');

    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod));        

    function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) 
    {
        if (web.get_effectiveBasePermissions().has(SP.PermissionKind.editListItems)) 
        {
            //User Has Edit Permissions
            alert('YEAH, edit list permissions!');
        }
    }
}
```

from http://spdailytips.blogspot.se/2011/09/check-current-user-permission.html

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee556747%28v=office.14%29.aspx) you can find all the possible values for the Enum SP.PermissionKind.

This pattern will work on a List or a ListItem as well (like a page). Just make sure to load the object with `context.load(theItem, 'EffectiveBasePermissions');`

So in your case `manageWeb` should do great!

Comment: Is there a reason to get the `currentUser` object? can you do without this?

Comment: Full control means FullMask or ManageWeb permsission ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way that worked for me:

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/678653/how-to-check-user-permission-for-the-web-list-or-s

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();

var ob = new SP.BasePermissions();
ob.set(SP.PermissionKind.editListItems)

var per = web.doesUserHavePermissions(ob)
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
  function(){ 
      alert(per.get_value()); // true if user has permission 
    },
 function(a,b){
     alert ("Something wrong");
 }
);
```